# Não está imprimindo minhas checkbox selecionadas

Tags: php

Boa noite, criei 3 checkbox e fiz um método array para quando eu clicar em **enviar** ele me mostra as checkbox selecionada com o seu `value`, mas não esta ocorrendo isso, fiz esse esquema pois estou testando para que eu coloque no meu formulário original que vou precisar listar meus checkbox selecionados...

Alguém pode me ajudar?

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Teste de checkbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Teste de check</h1>

    <form method="post" action="form.php">

    <input type="checkbox" name="cor" value="azul">

    <input type="checkbox" name="cor" value="vermelho">

    <input type="checkbox" name="cor" value="amarelo">


    <input type="submit" name="olhar">

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

form.php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["cor"])) {

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["cor"]); $i++) {

        echo "a cor ".$_POST["cor"] [$i]." foi selecionada";

    }
}

?>
```

Obrigado...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou só você "vetorizar" o seus inputs, como você utilizou o mesmo nome, e depois quer recuperar o valor de todos, precisa ser dessa forma:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">

<input type="checkbox" name="cor[]" value="azul">

<input type="checkbox" name="cor[]" value="vermelho">

<input type="checkbox" name="cor[]" value="amarelo">


<input type="submit" name="olhar">

</form>
```

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: Obrigado... ajudou bastante

Comment: O curioso é que até dá pra receber POST de nomes repetidos em PHP sem isso, mas dá um trabalhão danado.

Comment: Sério? acho que já tinha visto alguém falar sobre, mas nesses casos sempre uso dessa forma, quando necessário...

Comment: @LocalHost em PHP o [] é o caminho mais adequado mesmo, mas sempre pondo o "value" nesses casos. O fato é que quando repete o nome, não é um limite do POST, mas o próprio PHP sobreescreve o valor anterior. O POST vai com todos os dados. cor=a&cor=b*cor=c, então pro PHP só vale o último. Como no PHP o [] significa "o próximo indice livre", aí fica um array.

Comment: Um site bom pra testar isso é o https://httpbin.org/ - experimente fazer um form para `httpbin.org/post` sem usar os `[]`, você vai ver que mesmo assim ele consegue pegar todos os values marcados. Segue um link demonstrando: http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/pNBGag

Comment: Interessante @Bacco, não tinha conhecimento do modo de gravação do POST, mas a do array sabia por conta do próprio PHP mesmo

Comment: Comentei mais de curiosidade, em PHP não tem nem o que pensar, é isso que vc respondeu mesmo.